# On using bootstrap in rails, contents of "nav pull-right" disappears when window is resized to small

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am using bootstrap for creating twitter like app. The contents on the nav bar, under "nav pull-right" disappears when the window size resized to small. How do i do that? Here is my erb file..

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "cntwitter", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right" id="right_nav">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Account <b class="caret"></b> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The twitter bootstrap scaffolding, or grid, is static by default. It sounds like you want the contents of your web page to scale with the browser window. In that case, I would recommend using the "fluid" scaffolding :: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: Thanks imgrgry..

I got the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218886/twitter-bootstrap-navigation-bar-fixed